# Not able to see which API is Throwing eroor in log file - Spring-Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback

Hi i'm using logback in springboot, it is just storing error message only into error.log file. I need to see which api is throwing that error. please help me.

sample error.log file:

2018-12-06 00:02:11 [http-nio-8085-exec-2] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'tabless' at line 1

Here i'm not able to see which API is throwing this error.

logback.xml file:

```
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />

<property name="LOG_DIR" value="/opt/appLogs/" />

<!--Console log-->
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            %date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>

<!--log file config-->

<appender name="INFO" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

    <file>${LOG_DIR}/log.log</file>

    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>
            ${LOG_DIR}/archived/log_%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>100MB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>

</appender>

<!-- error file configuration-->
<appender name="error_file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

    <file>${LOG_DIR}/error.log</file>

    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
           %date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>
            ${LOG_DIR}/archived/error_%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>100MB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
        <level>ERROR</level>
        <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>

</appender>

<logger name="com.app.test" level="DEBUG" additivity="false" >
    <appender-ref ref="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</logger>

<root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="error_file" />
</root>
```

Comment: please share you config

Comment: added logback.xml file please help me.

Comment: Try to use this pattern:

%nopex %d{dd/MM/yyyy-HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}:%L - %xException{full}%n

Comment: why don't you log complete stack trace @DilliBabuKadati

Comment: Mykhailo Moskura, i tried your pattern but still not getting

Comment: Deadpool, Can you please explain me